# PLAY button in the middle of site header (CSS,HTML)

Tags: html, css

So, I have this id for div:

```
#button{
    width: 1280px;
    text-align: center;
}

#panel{
    position:absolute; 
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: center;
}

    <div id="panel">
       <img position="absolute" src="http://www.ionixpower.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Grass-globe-1-1280x500.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="button">
       <img src="http://2.firepic.org/2/images/2015-11/07/k9l53oj2fqg7.png">
    </div>
```

It contains an image that is 1280 pixels in width, a header picture.

I need to place a PLAY button in the middle of this picture, so that it won't go away from it if I resize the browser window or zoom in or out; though this button needs to be centered in most of existing resolutions.

How do I do this?

Comment: Post more of your code.

Comment: @nenad-vracar
Added some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/1rt9g601/2/

HTML

```
<div id="panel">
   <button class="play">Play button</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#panel {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/1980x960');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-35px, -20px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-35px, -20px);
     transform:translate(-35px, -20px);
}
```

Comment: I do need this picture to be resizable, but the button should still be in the middle of it.

Comment: Picture is responsive because of `background-size: cover;`. Try it and you will see

Comment: Nope, it stays the same.

Comment: You can use try this instead `background-size: 100% 100%;`